# jQuery .html a button can't be hit

Tags: jquery, html

can someone explain to me why when i add a button by jQuery

```
$("#foo").html("<button id='hello'>Hello</button>");
```

I actually have try with .on, .load but doesn't change anything...

When i click it he doesn't work, i'm actually using it to interact with socket so when i click it's suppose to say something to my socket server, but hit the button just does nothing!

Why we can't hit the button? maybe cause he doesn't appear in the source code(right click) when use this method?

EDIT My example code:

```
socket.emit('setContainer', "<button id='hello'>Hello</button>");
```

client.js

```
socket.on('setContainer', function(data)    {
    $('#container').html(data); 
});
```

here socket server send button to html, when i press this button it's supposed to start simple console.log event

```
$('#essai').on("click", function() {
    console.log('123');
    //start answer to socket but button doesn't work
    socket.emit('helloBack', "123");
});
```

but i don't know why here the button doesn't have any effect, when we click its like the button is locked or something else (i don't see the click effect when i click the button)

Comment: What have you done till now? Share some code as well.

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: Answer actually doesn't work, i'm going to show more code to explain the situation

Comment: post edited, if it can help u

Answer (score 1):

When you add the button dynamically, you need to attach event handlers on it directly

```js
var button = $('<button id="hello">Hello</button>');
button.click(function() {
  console.log('hello');
});
$("#foo").html(button);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**or** with delegation using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like

```js
$("#foo").html("<button id='hello'>Hello</button>");
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  console.log('hello');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.delegate()` method in order to attach handler to a node that's not in DOM yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my problem is resolve, here is the solution : (example) foo is the div who contain the #hello button id added by jQuery

```
$('#foo').on('click', '#hello', function() {
    socket.emit('helloBack', {
        response:   "hello"
    });
});
```